# Records apart form max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

[image]

I have been helped by Metal to write a SQL as below

```
select id  
        , OrderDate
        , RejectDate
        , max(case when RejectDate = '1900-01-01' then '9999-12-31' else RejectDate end) as rSum
     from tableA
     group by id, OrderDate, RejectDate
```

Now, I would like to find out all the records for a partcular id below the max reject date to delete them from a transformation table

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `row_number()`:

```
select 
    id,  
    OrderDate,
    RejectDate
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by id
            order by case when RejectDate = '1900-01-01' then '9999-12-31' else RejectDate end desc
        ) rn
    from tableA t
) t
where rn > 1
```

The advantage of this technique is that it avoids aggregation, which *may* lead to better performance. Also, you can easily turn this into a `delete` statement by leveraging the concept of updateable CTE, as follows:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        row_number() over(
            partition by id
            order by case when RejectDate = '1900-01-01' then '9999-12-31' else RejectDate end desc
        ) rn
    from tableA t
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(RejectDate) as MaxRejectDate
    FROM tableA) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.RejectDate < t2.MaxRejectDate
```

Comment: SELECT t1.ID,t1.RejectDate,t1.ORDERDATE,t2.MaxRejectDate
FROM vBuyerOrder t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT VHVIN, max(case when Rejectdate= '1900-01-01' then '9999-12-31' else RejectDate) as MaxRejectDate
    FROM vBuyerOrder where VHVIN='MRXXXXX7' group by ID) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.RejectDate < t2.MaxRejectDate I still get two rows of data for id. What am I doing wrong

Comment: I believe the issue with my solution is that the case statement needs to be applied to the t1 instance of your table. It would be easier for us to help you out with SQL to create your unique situation. Rather than fixing my answer, give GMB's answer a try. If that one works, I'll delete my answer.